# Python get data from MySchoolMenus.com

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to get the lunch menu for my school, which is on [MySchoolMenus.com](https://myschoolmenus.com). I'm using the python request module. When I do

```
r = request.get("https://www.myschoolmenus.com/instance/473/district/463/school/3915/menu/22927")
print(r.content)
```

It only returns the HTML non of the lunch options.

Comment: The page could be loading the actual data using javascript, in which case you should look into using Selenium or something that will execute that javascript before trying to get the content. You'll find lots of questions about it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the data from the following API:

```
GET https://www.myschoolmenus.com/api/v1/public/menu/{menu_id}
```

It also need the `x-district` header with the same district value as in the url path, in this case `463`

The following code retrieves the data:

```py
import requests

r = requests.get(
    "https://www.myschoolmenus.com/api/v1/public/menu/22927",
    headers={
        "x-district": "463"
    })

print(r.json()["data"])
```

Comment: Thank you, I have been trying to find an api